# ETA Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm currently working on a App that is similar to uber.

I got the location of the user and the location of the cab in firebase in real time.

The thing is, how can i get an ETA from the cab's position to the users position.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Comment: ETA should be based on the traffic data and the distance calculation. Not sure how but this link can be handy https://eng.uber.com/engineering-an-efficient-route/

Comment: @terril thomas That's a nice one, but i don't need a routing engine, because I already know the routes that the cab will take, just like the bus. We know the route of the bus... The same here, i just need a method to get an ETA from de marker of the cab's location to the marker of the user's location...

Comment: When you generate the route in Google Maps it returns the distance and time. So the ETA will be the current time plus the time returned by the route calculation.

Comment: But i don't have a route. I mean, i have some polylines that specify the route of the bus...

Comment: I think for Traffic Data you can keep some threshold value which can be approximated based on the distance. Like 5km might take 30 minutes based on the traffic data available from Google you can add the threshold value. Also, depends on how much distance has you covered from the initial state.

Comment: This link : https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Maps-calculate-your-ETA/answer/Richard-Russell?srid=oiKf

Comment: Wow @terril thomas that was a niceone. Actually, my app works with a GPS that is in Every cab/bus and it sends the Average Speed every 5 seconds...considering this, maybe i can use the info of the GPS and just get the distance between the user and the cab... it wont be as exact as Google, that would be the isssue